# How to chain eloquent relations in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

So far I was extracting the relation objects as arrays and then doing something like:

```
App\Model::find($id)
```

But however is there a way to do something like:

```
Auth::user()->group()->members()
```

It works until `Auth::user()->group` but no further chaining. Please help if you've done something. Or I'm just newbie.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You could use eager loading to load the user's group and then load all of the members of that group.

```
$user = User::with(['group', 'group.members'])->find(1);

// OR if you already have a user object (Like when using the Auth facade)
$user = Auth::user()->load(['group', 'group.members']);

foreach ($user->group->members as $member) {
    // Do something with a member
}
```

However, if you essentially want to jump down the structure a level, and get all the members related to a user, you could use the `hasManyThrough` relationship, in that a user has many members, through a group.

```
// In your User model
public function members()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Member::class, Group::class);
}
```

That way you can simply access the members directly through the user:

```
$members = Auth::user()->members;
```

Instead of doing a query to access the user's group and then doing another query to access that group's members, Laravel would use a single query with a join to get you the members.

Take a look at the hasManyThrough relationship [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
Auth::user()->group->members
```

Comment: I must have missed it somewhere. Thanks for this (:

Comment: Thats fine @TheAkashRajput. :). Above answer is really more illustrative. We should always accept the best one. thanks :)

Comment: Note that this works because `group()` is a `belongsTo` relationship that, when is accessed using a dynamic property,  returns a `Group` model