# Chain an array of model relationships to query builder

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

How can I chain an array of relations to a query builder instance in Laravel?

I currently have an array of relations passed in from another part of the system. Something like this:

```php
$relations = [
   "company",
   "staff",
   "category",
]
```

I've then got an instance of a model, and want to loop and add each relation, then get a certain property on the model. The length of the relations array is dynamic.

`$instance->company->staff->category->name;`

How can I achieve something like this?

**Edit:** To add context as to why I'd like to do this, I have a class which is using reflection to retrieve the class to instantiate. I have a property being passed to it which is generated something like `organization.company.staff.category.name`, where the first item `organization` is the model, which is instantiated with reflection and the last item `name` is the property which should be retrieved.

The varying items between the first and last are relations to go through to retrieve the property. We are retrieving this from a JSON value for a reporting platform, so we want to do something like this where we are able to re-use the same code to retrieve data system-wide. The content `organization.company.staff.category.name` will obviously change per JSON value.

Comment: why you need to do this? please explain

Comment: @r89human Please see the edit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to chain eloquent relations in laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40057334/how-to-chain-eloquent-relations-in-laravel)

Answer (score -1):

you can make a foreach, see my example

***Example***

```php
$relations = [
   "company",
   "staff",
   "category",
];

$producto = Producto::find(1);

foreach($relations as $relation){ $producto = $producto->$relation; )}

return $producto->name;
```

Comment: i think you lack understanding of the question itself. sorry.